# how to draw a process flow figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to draw the process like in the picture using the code below, however, there is some problem, would someone help me?

[image]

```
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}
    \usepackage{verbatim}

        \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
        \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]


    \tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=20em, text centered]
    \tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]



    \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down]
    \node[bag] { $(B)$}
        child {
            node[bag] {$(R_{good})$}
                child {
                    node[bag] {$(and)$}
                    edge from parent
                    node[right]  {$and$}
                }
                edge from parent
                node[right] {$t$}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Instead of posting only code snippets, you should post complete minimal example documents. That makes it easier for others to help you. Also, you should avoid general statements like "there is some problem": It's better to explain in words how your output differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want something like:

[image]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm}}

\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth]
\node[bag]{$(B)$} 
    child{ edge from parent node[right]{t}; \node[bag]{$(Rgood)$}
            child{ edge from parent node[right]{and}; \node[bag]{$(and)$}
                    child[missing]
                    child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{it}; \node[bag]{$(path1)$}}
                    child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{else}; \node[bag]{$(path2)$}}
            }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I actually removed the unused style `end`, changed the deprecate syntax `tikzstyle` with the equivalent `tikzset`. Moreover, for the leaves, i made use of the option `missing` to let `path1` be exactly below the previous `and`. You can add an arrow by simply inserting it as option of the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: thanks, however, in the picture, the connector is an arrow. I don't know how to draw the arrow to connect two objects.

Comment: @sweetyBaby: you are right. I've edited my answer to accomplish this, however for it I would recommend you to reference to the pgfmanual.

Comment: As we can see, in latex image in the above, two arrows are different. For example "and->path1" and "and->path2", the arrow connecting "and -> path2" is bolder than that of "and->path1", why?

Comment: Actually, in the code there are no option that can made one arrow bolder than the other one. I don't have an answer for this, sorry.