# Dashing one edge from parent in a tree: why does it work

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

This is related to the question [How to make a connection in a tree with a dashed line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67036/how-to-make-a-connection-in-a-tree-with-a-dashed-line).  Therein, it is asked how one can make *one* connection between a parent node and a child dashed.

The final solution proposed is along the line of  alternating the `edge from parent[solid]` and `edge from parent[dashed]`, which is not only ugly, but also incomplete: when *drawing* `nodes` at each `child`, the node inherits (albeit in a weird fashion) the `dashed` or `solid` property of the `edge from parent`.

Let's start with a common preamble:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\def\es{edge from parent[solid]}
\def\ed{edge from parent[dashed]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw},level/.style={sibling distance=20mm/#1}]
```

Now let's start with what is *natural* to write.

```
  \node {}
  child{
    node {}
    child{
      node {}
      child{
        node {}
        child{node{}}
        child}
      child{node{}}}
    child
    child{
      child}
    \ed}
  child {child[missing] child{child} child {child{child child} child}};
```

this outputs:

[image: First example]

This was the original problem called for in the aforementioned question.

The proposed solution, adding `\es` every other places, resuts in:

```
  \node {}
  child{
    node {}
    child{
      node {}
      child{
        node {}
        child{node{}}
        child}
      child{node{}}
      \es}
    child{\es}
    child{
      child
      \es}
    \ed}
  child {child[missing] child{child} child {child{child child} child}};
```

which is displayed as:

[image: Second]

has two serious problems: the redundancy, and the fact that a node appears dashed.

Finally, after many attempts, I came up with the following solution:

```
  \node {}
  child{
    node {}
    child{
      node {}
      child{
        node {}
        child{node{}}
        child}
      child{node{}}}
    child
    child{
      child};
    \path \ed;}
  child {child[missing] child{child} child {child{child child} child}}
```

which nicely displays as:

[image: Third]

**Question:** Why?  Why do I need a `\path`?  Why doesn't it work with just `\ed`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I hope it's ok to provide an answer which is not really an answer but an advertisement for my own (`tikz`-based) tree drawing package, `forest`. (Until recently, it's available on `ctan` and also included in TeX Live.)

In `forest`, the properties of each node and parent-child edge can be set individually.  So the stated problem is solved by simply saying `edge=dashed` at the desired location. (If one wants to set this property for the whole (sub)tree, `for tree={edge=dashed}` must be used.)

Here's the code. I didn't bother with specifying some nodes as coordinates, since this is irrelevant for the answer, but it can be done: just say `coordinate` at the node. I did demonstrate what to do with the `missing` node, though.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={draw}
  [
    [,edge=dashed[[[][]][]][][[]]]
    [,calign=first[[]][[[][]][]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result]