# How can I coerce TikZ trees to have directed edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, tikz-arrows

Consider the following

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{A} [grow=east]
  child {node{B}
    child {node{C}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: output]

How can I coerce each edge to have arrow heads so that I can have something like `A->B->C`?
(Let's assume the style `[->,>=stealth]`.)

Comment: is [TikZ: turning edges into arrows using "child" notation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70296) related/helpful?

Comment: @cmhughes Looks like a duplicate to me; my apologies :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `edge from parent` key.  If you do it after the first node it will propagate to all edges below that node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{A} [grow=east, ]
  child {node{B} edge from parent[-stealth]
    child {node{C}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

See §18.6 of the TikZ manual for details.