# How to Create Directed Graphs in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-trees, graphs, trees

How can one create a tree structure in LaTeX that begins with a single number and extends with an arbitrary number of arrows that connect numbers below with numbers above such that the head faces upward?  For example, a tree of this form:

I see that there are similar trees without directed arrows as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151042/forest-different-growing-directions-for-branches-on-the-same-level).  Similarly, I see that there are trees with directed arrows that are not similar as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159386/how-can-i-coerce-tikz-trees-to-have-directed-edges).  Is there a way to combine these two elements in tikz?

Is simply copying the following elements from `\usepackage{tikz,forest}` sufficient or are entirely different elements needed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}

\begin{document}
\texttt{grow} used in a Ti\textit{k}Z tree

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{1}
    child{node{child 1}}
    child[grow=south]{node{child 2}
      child child child
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
end{forest}
end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Read about the `edge from parent` syntax and style in the TikZ manual.

Comment: @Bordaigorl Thanks I'll take a look at that.

Comment: If you take a minute to write a MWE where you draw the tree in the picture without the arrows I can show you how to set them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [forest](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) solution which numbers the nodes automatically:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\bracketset{action character=@}% based on code from page 22 of forest's manual
\newcount\xcount
\def\x{@@\advance\xcount1
  \edef\xtemp{$\noexpand{\the\xcount}$}%
  \expandafter\bracketResume\xtemp
}
\begin{forest}
  delay={%
        content={#1}%
  },
  for tree={%
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path[<-, \forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
  @+
  [\x
    [\x
      [\x
        [\x
          [\x]
          [\x]
          [\x]
        ]
        [\x
          [\x]
          [\x]
        ]
        [\x
          [\x]
        ]
      ]
      [\x]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: automatically numbering nodes with forest]

Comment: Sorry, how would I centre this diagram?

Comment: @Blender With respect to what? Do you just want to wrap it in `\begin{center}...\end{center}`?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the new graphs stuff in the latest PGF with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]    
\graph  [tree layout, grow=down]{
  1 <- 2 <- {
    3 <- {
      5 <- {10,11,12}, 6 <- {13,14}, 7 <- {,15}
    }, 
    4 <- {,/}
  };   
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I already have a document with a \documentclass how do I add in this new document class?  Simply adding it below the other results in an error.

Comment: @Blender with another document class (e.g., article) you would just replace the first line in the example above with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz}`.