# Edge style for binary tree layout

Tags: tikz-pgf

According to this answer: [TikZ: turning edges into arrows using "child" notation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70296/tikz-turning-edges-into-arrows-using-child-notation)
one can set the style of edges for the node / child notation with the key `edges from parent/.style`.

However, this is not working if I use the `binary tree layout`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    binary tree layout,
    edge from parent/.style={->, thick},
  ]
  \node {a}
    child{node {b} }
    child{node {c} }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

How can I style the edges with `binary tree layout`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Lua graph drawing facilities, why not use the graph syntax?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\tikz\graph [binary tree layout] { a -> {b, c}};

\end{document}
```

[image: graphed tree]

To style the edges, you can just add the information to the specification for the graph. For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

  \tikz\graph [binary tree layout, edges={thick}] { a -> {b, c}};

\end{document}
```

[image: styled edges]

Note that if you prefer to specify the diagram using the standard `node`/`child` syntax, then you are not really making use of the `graphs` library, although you could still use the `graphdrawing` library (see below). In that case, it might be easier to just drop the `binary tree layout` and specify the shape the tree will take yourself. In this case, just drop the graphs and graph drawing stuff:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    edge from parent/.style={draw, ->, thick},
  ]
  \node {a}
    child{node {b} }
    child{node {c} }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

for very similar output:

[image: non-graph tree]

You can also use the `graphdrawing` library with the more standard syntax. In that case, you can apply a style to the edges using `every edge/.style={}`. However, specifying `->` apparently has no effect:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [binary tree layout, every edge/.style={draw=blue, thick, ->}]
  \node {a}
    child{node {b} }
    child{node {c} }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: no arrows despite styling the edges]

Presumably there is some workaround for this, but my brief experiments did not discover it.

Comment: And where do I apply styles for the edges? That's the question.

Comment: You just add it to the specification for the graph. See edit above.

Comment: Added a couple of further options but I'm not sure why `->` is ineffective in the last tree.

Comment: Can I apply individual styling to nodes using the `\graph` command?

Comment: And you say with using the node/child syntax I'm not using the graph drawing algorithm, but the results are vastly different if I provide this option or not. What's the reason for this?

Comment: Actually, on reflection, I'm not sure. I don't entirely understand the relationship between `graphs` and `graphdrawing`. I thought I did, but I think I thought wrongly.

Comment: @MaxNoe I've corrected my answer, I think. I don't get significantly different results for the node/child syntax with versus without `binary tree layout` *unless* I also specify some further stuff using e.g. `every edge`.

Comment: I get significantly different results for larger nodes.

Comment: @MaxNoe I only tested very minimally ;).